# Unable to install software for Huawei EC169 CDMA USB Modem

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem, huawei

I'm using this Huawei EC169 CDMA USB Modem that's provided as a standard by PTCL in Pakistan when it comes to 3G connectivity.
The issue I'm having right now is that I have tried installing the Linux SW driver provided on PTCL's website

Here's the link; http://ptcl.com.pk/related_pages.php?pd_id=203&rp_id=146

After unzipping the contents & trying to execute the commands in terminal, I'm unsuccessful. I am just lost.

I'm on the prepaid plan basically & I need the Mobile Partner UI to recharge the vouchers.

I'm able to connect through the USB to internet without the standard UI; but it's really of no use once the credit limit runs out.

If anyone of you could be kind enough to run me through the details of commands that I am supposed to execute, it'd be really great because many others on the Pakistani Tech forums using Linux need help with this issue.

Right now I'm using Lubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

@araiqa, I assume that the .zip file you downloaded in the ~/Downloads directory and you extracted it in the same directory. If this is the case, then the commands you have to run as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads/linux SW/Linux13.305.05.00.03/driver
sudo ./install
```

After the last command, you will be asked where it should be installed. Writed down /usr/local/Mobile_Partner

With this, the installation will be finished.

I hope this will help you.